# scala.slick.SlickException: JdbcProfile has no JdbcType for type UnassignedType - on Option fields

Tags: postgresql, scala, exception, mapping, slick

I was successfully mapped case classes w/o Optional fields to Postgres db via class that extends Table.
Now I need to use case class with Optional[String] and Optional[DateTime] fields.

I has found how to declare mapping for it:

```
case class Issue(id: Int,
  key: String,
...
  resolutionName: Option[String],
  resolutionDate: Option[DateTime],
             )

case class Issues(tag: Tag) extends Table[Issue](tag, "Issues") {
// This is the primary key column:
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def key = column[String]("key")
... 
  def resolutionName = column[String]("resolutionName")
  def resolutionDate = column[DateTime]("resolutionDate")

  def * = (id, key, resolutionName.?, resolutionDate.?) <> (Issue.tupled, Issue.unapply)
}
```

Code compiles well but during runtime I get exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.slick.SlickException: JdbcProfile has no JdbcType for type UnassignedType
    at scala.slick.driver.JdbcTypesComponent$class.jdbcTypeFor(JdbcTypesComponent.scala:66)
    at scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver$.jdbcTypeFor(PostgresDriver.scala:151)
    at scala.slick.driver.JdbcTypesComponent$JdbcType$.unapply(JdbcTypesComponent.scala:49)
```

What shall I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The columns must be defined as `Option`s too:

```
def resolutionName = column[Option[String]]("resolutionName")
def resolutionDate = column[Option[DateTime]]("resolutionDate")
```

Also you can avoid the `.?`in the projections function since that values are already mapped as options:

```
def * = (id, key, resolutionName, resolutionDate) <> (Issue.tupled, Issue.unapply)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now! (sorry, I can't vote for your answer as I don't have enough scores of reputation here)